# How to use " iloc " and " loc " method in place of .ix method for index slicing let's just say to get the data between a particular time frame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
sns.distplot(returns.ix['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31']['MS Return'],color='green',bins=100)
```

while running this code I am getting an error so how to replace it with '`iloc`' and '`loc`' method.

The data head is as below:

```
BAC Return  C Return    GS Return   JPM Return  MS Return   WFC Return
```

Date

```
2017-12-29  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-12-28  0.009485    0.009004    0.006830    0.007948    0.003431    0.010384
2017-12-27  -0.002349   -0.002531   -0.002144   -0.005288   -0.001519   -0.005710
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as you did with .ix, 
   start, end - datetime format, not a string

dataframe.loc[start:end]

And check first if dataframe.index returns you datetime instead of integers
Otherwise use dataframe.set_index() method

Answer (score 0):

iloc and loc split the job ix did in two.

Use iloc to address the dataset like a numpy array (eg returns.iloc[10:20,0:5], .head() is equivalent to .iloc[:5]).

Use loc to access a row by index so your code should read:

```
sns.distplot(returns.loc['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31']['MS Return'],color='green',bins=100)
```